# Will Scala's parallel collections guarantee ordering?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, parallel-collections

If I have this:

```
val a = Array(...)
```

and I write

```
a.par.map(e => someFunc(e))
```

Will the resulting collection be in the same order as the non-parallel collection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [scala: with parallel collection, does aggregate respect order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303878/scala-with-parallel-collection-does-aggregate-respect-order)

Comment: I now regret tagging it as duplicate. I have reread the other question, and the emphasis is not on iterate, but on aggregate.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, but the function itself is executed without any particular order.

```
List(1,2,3).par foreach print // could print out 213
```

Comment: Is the order guaranteed for any collection that supports parallelism?

Comment: Yes and btw I just noticed that there is a possible duplicate [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303878/scala-with-parallel-collection-does-aggregate-respect-order)

Comment: I saw the aggregate link, but I think it's not exactly duplicate.

Answer (score 16):

The parallel collections maintain all of the contracts of their non-parallel equivalents.

On collections in which a `map` operation preserves order, such as `List`, order will be preserved by the parallel `map` as well. On collections in which `map` does not preserve order, such as `Set`, order will not be preserved in the parallel version.

With unordered collections, there is no guarantee that the result of a parallel operation will even have the same traversal order as its non-parallel equivalent.

Comment: Would you have some reference (doc, or unit test in scala lib)? I trust you that it does in practice (I tried), but I need it to be guarantied

Comment: It's touched on here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html (Note that transparency is given as a motivating quality for the design. The section on semantics discusses cases where non-determinism arises and states that results from partitioned computations are combined _in order_.)