# Fold and foldLeft method difference

Tags: scala

I am not sure what is the difference between `fold` and `foldLeft` in Scala.

The question [Difference between fold and foldLeft or foldRight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253978/difference-between-fold-and-foldleft-or-foldright) has an answer that talks about ordering. That is understandable. But I still don't understand why this works (from REPL):

```
scala> Array("1","2","3").foldLeft(0)(_ + _.toInt)
res6: Int = 6
```

but this does not:

```
scala> Array("1","2","3").fold(0)(_ + _.toInt)
<console>:8: error: value toInt is not a member of Any
              Array("1","2","3").fold(0)(_ + _.toInt)
                                               ^
```

What does this error message mean?

This line from the documentation is also confusing to me.

> **z** - a neutral element for the fold operation; may be added to the
>   result an arbitrary number of times, and must not change the result
>   (e.g., Nil for list concatenation, 0 for addition, or 1 for
>   multiplication.)

Why will it be added *an arbitrary number of times*? I thought folding works differently.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As defined by Scala, `foldLeft` is a linear operation while `fold` is allowed to be a tree operation.  For example:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5).foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
// This is the only valid order of operations
0+1 = 1
      1+2 = 3
            3+3 = 6
                  6+4 = 10
                        10 + 5 = 15
                                 15  // done

List(1,2,3,4,5).fold(0)(_ + _)
// This is valid
0+1 = 1             0+3 = 3           0+5 = 5
      1+2 = 3             3+4 = 7           5
            3         +         7=10        5
                                  10    +   5 = 15
                                                15  // done
```

In order to allow arbitrary tree decompositions of a sequential list, you must have a zero that doesn't do anything (so you can add it wherever you need it in the tree) and you must create the same sort of thing that you take as your binary arguments so the types don't change on you depending on how you decompose the tree.

(Being able to evaluate as a tree is nice for parallelization.  If you want to be able to transform your output time as you go, you need both a combination operator *and* a standard start-value-transforms-sequence-element-to-desired-type function just like `foldLeft` has.  Scala has this and calls it `aggregate`, but in some ways this is more like `foldLeft` than `fold` is.)

Comment: I like the explanation, good work, but it doesn't answer the question. The question was "why does fold example doesn't work?". The point that fold is in parallel makes that the init value and result has to be a super type of the collection, that's the reason why this fold example doesn't work.

Comment: @CarlosVerdes - I don't think you read my answer carefully enough.  In the paragraph after the example block I explained exactly what you said the point was.  Except I not only explained what the problem was, but also why.

Answer (score 30):

I am not familiar with Scala, but Scala's collection library has a similar design to Haskell's.  This answer is based on Haskell and is probably accurate for Scala as well.

Because `foldLeft` processes its inputs from left to right, it can have different input and output types.  On the other hand, `fold` can process its inputs in various orders and so the inputs and output must all have the same type.  This is easiest to see by expanding out the fold expressions.  `foldLeft` operates in a specific order:

```
Array("1","2","3").foldLeft(0)(_ + _.toInt)
= ((0 + "1".toInt) + "2".toInt) + "3".toInt
```

Note that array elements are never used as the first parameter to the combining function.  They always appear on the right of the `+`.

`fold` does not guarantee a specific order.  It could do various things, such as:

```
Array("1","2","3").fold(0)(_ + _.toInt)
=  ((0 + "1".toInt) + "2".toInt) + "3".toInt
or (0 + "1".toInt) + ("2" + "3".toInt).toInt
or "1" + ("2" + ("3" + 0.toInt).toInt).toInt
```

Array elements can appear in either parameter of the combining function.  But your combining function expects its first argument to be an int.  If you don't respect that constraint, you end up adding strings to ints!  This error is caught by the type system.

The neutral element may be introduced multiple times because, generally, a parallel fold is implemented by splitting up the input and executing multiple sequential folds.  A sequential fold introduces the neutral element once.  Imagine one particular execution of `Array(1,2,3,4).fold(0)(_ + _)` where the array is split into two separate arrays, and these are folded sequentially in two threads.  (Of course, the real `fold` function does not spit the array into multiple arrays.)  One thread executes `Array(1,2).fold(0)(_ + _)`, computing `0 + 1 + 2`.  The other thread executes `Array(3,4).fold(0)(_ + _)`, computing `0 + 3 + 4`.  Finally, the partial sums from the two threads are added together.  Note that the neutral element, `0`, appears twice.

Comment: The advantage of `fold` over `foldleft` is that `fold` can process the data in parallel and `foldLeft` is linear so that `fold` can be faster then `foldLeft`. Is that right?

Answer (score 15):

NOTE: I could be completely wrong here.  My scala is less than perfect.

I think that the difference is in the signature of the methods:

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1
```

vs

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, T) ⇒ B): B
```

In short, fold is defined as operating on some type A1 which is a supertype of the array's type, which for your string array the compiler defines as "Any" (probably because it needs a type that can store your String *or* an int- notice that the combiner method passed to fold Fold takes two parameters of the same type?)  That's also what the documentation means when it talks about z- the implementation of Fold could be such that it combines your inputs in parallel, for instance:

```
"1" + "2" --\
             --> 3 + 3 -> 6
"3" + *z* --/
```

On the other hand, foldLeft operates on type B (unconstrained) and only asks that you provide a combiner method that takes a parameter of type B and another of your array's type (String, in your case), and produces a B.

Comment: That is almost perfect. `A1` is a supertype `A` -- that is, I can go from `Int` to `Any` (for example), but not from `Any` to `Int`.

Comment: OK. In that case, I am not sure why it was cast to `Any` and not `AnyVal`. But other than that, I think I understand.

Comment: @KarelBílek presumably because it needs a base type common to String and int.  String is (again, assuming, because it is in Java) a reference type.

Answer (score 15):

**The error.** You are getting a compile-time error because the signature of `fold` only allows folding values of type which is the supertype of the type of the values in the collection, and the only supertype of `String` (your collection type) and `Int` (the type of your provided zero element) is `Any`. So, the type of the fold result is inferred to be `Any` - and `Any` does not have a method `toInt`.

Note that the two versions of `fold` have different signatures:

```
fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1

foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B
```

Why do they have different signatures? This is because `fold` could be implemented in parallel, as is the case with parallel collections. When multiple processors fold over the values in the collections, each one of the processors takes a subset of elements of type `A` and produces the folded value of type `A1`, by consecutively applying `op`. The results produced by those processors must be combined together into a final folding value - this is done using the `op` function, which does exactly that.

Now, note that this cannot be done using the `f` in `foldLeft`, because each of the processors  produces a folded value of type `B`. Several values of type `B` cannot be combined using `f`, because `f` only combines value `B` with another value of type `A` - there is no correspondance between types `A` and `B`.

**Example.** In your example, assume the 1st processor takes elements `"1", "2"` and the 2nd takes element `"3"`. The first one will produce the folded value `3`, and the second will produce another folded value `3`. Now they have to combine their results to get the final folded value - this is impossible, because the closure `_ + _.toInt` only knows how to combine an `Int` and `String`, and not 2 `Int` values.

For situations where these types differ, use `aggregate`, in which you have to define how to combine two values of type `B`:

```
def aggregate[B](z: B)(seqop: (B, A) => B, combop: (B, B) => B): B
```

The `combop` above defines how to do the final step when the fold result and the elements in the collection have different types.

**The neutral element.** As described above, multiple processors may fold over subsets of elements in the collection. Each one of them will start its folded value by adding the neutral element.

In the following example:

```
List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(4)(_ + _)
```

always returns `10 = 4 + 1 + 2 + 3`.

However, `4` should not be used with `fold`, as it is not a neutral element:

```
List(1, 2, 3).fold(4)(_ + _)
```

The above may return `(4 + 1 + 2) + (4 + 3) = 14` or `(4 + 1) + (4 + 2) + (4 + 3) = 18`. If you don't use the neutral element for the `fold`, the results are nondeterministic. In the same way, you can use the `Nil` as a neutral element, but not a non-empty list.

Answer (score 6):

As another answer points out, the `fold` method is primarily there to support a parallel fold. You can see this as follows. First we can define a kind of wrapper for integers that allows us to keep track of the operations that have been performed on its instances.

```
case class TrackInt(v: Int) {
  val log = collection.mutable.Buffer.empty[Int]
  def plus(that: TrackInt) = {
    this.log += that.v
    that.log += this.v
    new TrackInt(this.v + that.v)
  }
}
```

Next we can create a parallel collection of these things and an identity element:

```
val xs = (1 to 10).map(TrackInt(_)).par
val zero = TrackInt(0)
```

First we'll try `foldLeft`:

```
scala> xs.foldLeft(zero)(_ plus _)
res0: TrackInt = TrackInt(55)

scala> zero.log
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1)
```

So our zero value is only used once, as we'd expect, since `foldLeft` performs a sequential fold. Next we can clear the log and try `fold`:

```
scala> zero.log.clear()

scala> xs.fold(zero)(_ plus _)
res2: TrackInt = TrackInt(55)

scala> zero.log
res3: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 6, 2, 7, 8)
```

So we can see that the fold has been parallelized in such a way that the zero value is used multiple times. If we ran this again we'd be likely to see different values in the log.

Answer (score 5):

### General difference

Here are the prototypes of the methods

```
fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1
foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

So, for fold the result is of type `A1 >: A`instead of any `B`. Moreover, as specified in the doc, for `fold` the order is not

### About your error

When typing `scala> Array("1","2","3").fold(0)(_ + _.toInt)` you assume that `0`, an `int` is a subtype of `String`. This is why the compiler throws an error.

### About the weird z in fold

Here we have to see the [implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce.scala#L115) of `fold` to understand what happens. Here is what we get:

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1 = foldLeft(z)(op)
```

So basically, `fold` is an implementation of `foldleft` with a constraint on the output type.
We can now see that `z` will in practice be used the same way as in `foldleft`. So we can just conclude that this comment was made because nothing assures that behavior in future implementations. We can already see it now, with [parallels](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/parallel/ParIterableLike.scala#L397):

```
def fold[U >: T](z: U)(op: (U, U) => U): U = {
  executeAndWaitResult(new Fold(z, op, splitter))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been mentioned, but without example: If you want to allow parallelism with different data types for output and input, you could use [`aggregate`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List):

```
Array("1","2","3").aggregate(0)(_ + _.toInt, _ + _)
```

The first function gets called first. Its results are then reduced with the second function. See [Explanation of the aggregate scala function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761087/explanation-of-the-aggregate-scala-function).