# Is this a parallel fold operation?

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo

Definition of [fold](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$@fold[E,A](state:A)(f:(A,E)=%3EA)(implicitec:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[E,A]) from Play! API is

[image]

as the folding function takes two different types A , E does this mean this operation is not run in parallel ?

As according to [Fold and foldLeft method difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319111/fold-and-foldleft-method-difference) the type signature of fold (from Scala API) :

[image]

the op function takes two of same types (A1), this allows the operation to be run in parallel.

The fold operation itself is implemented in a new thread using `ExecutionContext` which is passed as an implicit. The fold type signature suggests it cannot be implemented in parallel, Iteratee.fold creates a new thread for the fold operation and therefore is non blocking. In summary fold is not a parallel operation but is non-blocking ? This is in contrast to Scala fold operation which can be run in parallel.

Comment: I assume that the mere fact that an aggregator is used prohibits any parallel execution. How would multiple aggregators resulting from partial processing be combined?

Comment: @Andreas Jim-Hartmann 'How would multiple aggregators resulting from partial processing be combined?' I don't know but any such combination would need to be associative I assume. It's probably safe to say that fold fomr Play! API is essentially the same as a foldLeft operation from Scala API ?

Comment: From the documentation this seems to be the case. The fold1 method seems to support asynchronous processing (see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Iteratees).