# Scala : fold vs foldLeft

Tags: scala, reduce, fold

I am trying to understand how fold and foldLeft and the respective reduce and reduceLeft work. I used fold and foldLeft as my example

```
scala> val r = List((ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4),10))
scala> r.foldLeft(ArrayBuffer(1,2,4,5))((x,y) => x -- y._1)

scala> res28: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(5)

scala> r.fold(ArrayBuffer(1,2,4,5))((x,y) => x -- y._1)
<console>:11: error: value _1 is not a member of Serializable with Equals
              r.fold(ArrayBuffer(1,2,4,5))((x,y) => x -- y._1)
```

Why `fold` didn't work as `foldLeft`? What is `Serializable with Equals`? I understand fold and foldLeft has slight different API signature in terms of parameter generic types. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between fold and foldLeft or foldRight?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6253978)

Comment: What version of scala?

Comment: My scala version is 2.10.1

Comment: Recommend you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158780/difference-between-reduce-and-foldleft-in-functional-programming-particularly-s

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The method `fold` (originally added for parallel computation) is less powerful than `foldLeft` in terms of types it can be applied to. Its signature is:

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1
```

This means that the type over which the folding is done has to be a supertype of the collection element type.

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

The reason is that `fold` can be implemented in parallel, while `foldLeft` cannot. This is not only because of the `*Left` part which implies that `foldLeft` goes from left to right sequentially, but also because the operator `op` cannot combine results computed in parallel -- it only defines how to combine the aggregation type `B` with the element type `A`, but not how to combine two aggregations of type `B`. The `fold` method, in turn, does define this, because the aggregation type `A1` has to be a supertype of the element type `A`, that is `A1 >: A`. This supertype relationship allows in the same time folding over the aggregation and elements, and combining aggregations -- both with a single operator.

But, this supertype relationship between the aggregation and the element type also means that the aggregation type `A1` in your example should be the supertype of `(ArrayBuffer[Int], Int)`. Since the zero element of your aggregation is `ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 4, 5)` of the type `ArrayBuffer[Int]`, the aggregation type is inferred to be the supertype of both of these -- and that's `Serializable with Equals`, the only least upper bound of a tuple and an array buffer.

In general, if you want to allow parallel folding for arbitrary types (which is done out of order) you have to use the method `aggregate` which requires defining how two aggregations are combined. In your case:

```
r.aggregate(ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 4, 5))({ (x, y) => x -- y._1 }, (x, y) => x intersect y)
```

Btw, try writing your example with `reduce`/`reduceLeft` -- because of the supertype relationship between the element type and the aggregation type that both these methods have, you will find that it leads to a similar error as the one you've described.