# Convert list of sortedset to sortedset in scala

Tags: scala, flatten, sortedset

(Still new to scala) I have a `List[SortedSet[A]]`, and I'd like a unique `SortedSet[A]` with all (unique and sorted) elements. How should I do that?

My goal is: I have a class, say `Container`, that contain a list of `Element` and a list of (sub)`Container`. This class should implement a recursive `getSortedElements(): SortedSet[Element]` methods.

So I easily have this invalid code:

```
case class Container(myElements: List[Element], myContainers: List[Container]){
    def getSortedElements(): SortedSet[Element] =
        SortedSet(myElements) ++ SortedSet(myContainers.map(_.getSortedElements))
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the output to be a `SortedSet` with all the items in ALL the `SortedSet`s in the `List`?

Comment: Yup. `List(SortedSet(3,5,7),SortedSet(2,5,8))` => `SortedSet(2,3,5,7,8)` but not with integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala's Set types already enforce uniqueness, so all you need to do is combine them:

```
val a = SortedSet(1,2,3)
val b = SortedSet(2,7,5)
val c = SortedSet(1, 9)
List(a, b, c).fold(SortedSet())((x, y) => x ++ y)
```

You can also use `reduce` instead of `fold`:

```
List(a, b, c).reduce((x, y) => x ++ y)
```

See [Scala : fold vs foldLeft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111440/scala-fold-vs-foldleft) for more about the differences between those