# Scala: get list with the first element of three lists not repeating any element

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming

I have a scala `List[List[Person]]` with the following elements:

```
Person(Antonio)
Person(Maria)
Person(Joao)

Person(Antonio)
Person(Susana)
Person(Laura)

Person(Maria)
Person(Manuel)
Person(Joao)
Person(Laura)
```

How can I get a list with the first element of each list not repeated? Like this:

```
Person(Antonio)
Person(Susana)
Person(Maria)
```

It would be easy to do with `var's`, but I want to do it functionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val l: List[List[Person]] = ...

l.foldLeft(List.empty[Person]) { case (acc, el) => 
  el.find(x => !acc.contains(x)).fold(acc)(acc.::)
}
```

Comment: This is not quite right. Instead of returning `Person(Antonio)/Person(Susana)/Person(Maria)` it is returning `Person(Antonio)/Person(Maria)`

Comment: I see, I didn't get that from your description... Updated

Comment: Folding on an option is a bit unusual, no? Maybe `acc ++ el.find(x => !acc.contains(x)).toList`?

Comment: Joe K's idea also works. With Olivier's solution I had to reverse the resulting list in order to get the right order, with Joe's tweak I don't have to do that.

Comment: Remarkable solution.  I would only add that the outer `foldLeft` could also be replaced with `fold` for potentially better [parallelization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111440/scala-fold-vs-foldleft).

Comment: @JoeK Prepending an element to a list takes linear time, appending and reversing at the end takes constant amortized time.

Comment: @LeoC In this case using foldRight instead of foldLeft would not yield the same result, this problems seems inherently not parallelizable.

Comment: "Folding on an option is a bit unusual, no". No. Not IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this with recursion and `foldLeft`:

```
val allLists: List[List[Person]] = ...

allLists.foldLeft(List.empty[Person]){ case(outputList, list) =>
  def loop(innerList: List[Person], newPerson: Person): Person = {
    if(innerList.isEmpty) newPerson
    else if(!outputList.contains(innerList.head)) newPerson
    else loop(innerList.tail, innerList.tail.head)
  }

  outputList :+ loop(list, list.head)
}
```