# How to convert a Set[String] to Map[String, String]?

Tags: scala

I want to convert a `Set` to a `Map`, something like:

```
val x: Set[String] = Set("asds", "reqrq", "dadas")
x.fold(Map.empty[String, String]) { 
  (p: Map[String, String], q: String) => p + (q ->  doSomething(q)) 
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (Map[String,String], String) => scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]
 required: (Object, Object) => Object
val res16 = x.fold(Map.empty[String, String]) { (p: Map[String, String], q: String) => p + (q ->  doSomething(q)) }
                                                                                    ^
```

How does one elegantly achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any `fold`s, just use `map` on the `Set`, and then convert the result `toMap`. Here is an example where `doSomething` is `_.toUpperCase`:

```
Set("a", "b").map(x => x -> x.toUpperCase).toMap
```

---

If you want to avoid building an intermediate set, you can use [`breakOut`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/breakout.html) to do everything in a single step:

```
val y: Map[String, String] = 
  Set("a", "b").map(x => x -> x.toUpperCase)(collection.breakOut)

// `y` is now `Map(a -> A, b -> B)`
```

Note that the types required for `breakOut` are inferred by the compiler from the context. If you are not assigning it to an explicitly typed local variable or passing it to a method that uniquely determines the expected type, you can always use an explicit type ascription

```
(Set("a", "b").map(x => x -> x.toUpperCase)(breakOut): Map[String, String])
```

to obtain an expression of the right type.

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez I'd rather treat the lengthy list of type parameters of `breakOut` as an implementation detail, and ascribe the type from the outside whenever possible, otherwise the type parameter list looks way too noisy and scary, and with too many redundant details ;]

Comment: Agree @Andrey Tyukin, its more clear and a lot less scary that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foldLeft` instead of `fold`:

```
val x: Set[String] = Set("asds", "reqrq", "dadas")
x.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, String]) { (p, q) =>
    p + (q -> doSomething(q))
}
```

Have a look at [Scala: fold vs foldLeft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111440/scala-fold-vs-foldleft) for the more detail.