# Why fold infers Any?

Tags: scala, types, type-inference, fold, type-mismatch

I'm compiling with Scala 2.11.12 and this declaration:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack
def stackToInt(stack: Stack[Int]): Int =
  stack.zipWithIndex.fold(0){ case (z: Int, (piece: Int, index: Int)) =>
    piece match {
      case 1 => (1 << index) + z
      case _ => z
    }
  }
```

gives:

```
stack.zipWithIndex.fold(0){ case (z: Int, (piece: Int, index: Int)) =>
                       ^
error: type mismatch;
        found   : Any
        required: Int
```

I've been dealing with stuff like this many times when writing folds in this project (first one in Scala) and I always found a different way to make it work, but maybe if I understand it I will stop hitting this wall.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111440/scala-fold-vs-foldleft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fold` method expects an associative binary operation as its second argument, i.e. some operation `f(_, _)` that satisfies

```
f(x, f(y, z)) = f(f(x, y), z)
```

Your folding function `f` combines an `Int` with an `(Int, Int)`.
It cannot be associative, because `f(x, f(y, z))` and `f(f(x, y), z)` cannot possibly type-check at the same time:

- If `f(x, f(y, z))` typechecks, then `x: Int` and `f(y, z): (Int, Int)`,
- But then, the return type of `f` must be `(Int, Int)`,
- But then, `f(f(x, y), z)` cannot typecheck, because it gets `(Int, Int)` in the first argument, where an `Int` is expected.

Therefore, it's not meaningful to talk about associativity here: the claim is not even false, it simply cannot be stated in the first place.

Since the operation is not associative, you cannot simply leave it to the language to decide in what order to process the elements; you *must* select a folding direction, i.e. decide whether it's

```
f(...f(f(f(a0, x1), x2), x3)...)
```

(foldLeft)

or

```
f(...f(x(n-3), f(x(n-2), f(x(n-1), a0))...)))))
```

(foldRight)

In your case, it must be `foldLeft`.

The type `Any` is inferred as the least upper bound between `Int` and `(Int, Int)`, because the compiler is attempting to interpret the `f` as an associative operation, which, necessarily, has two parameters of the same type.

Answer (score 3):

Because you need to use `foldLeft` instead of fold:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack
def stackToInt(stack: Stack[Int]): Int =
  stack.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(0) { case (z: Int, (piece: Int, index: Int)) =>
    piece match {
      case 1 => (1 << index) + z
      case _ => z
    }
  }
```

Scatie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/VzfKqHZ5QJyNPfwpLVGwSw

`fold` does not work because it's semantic: `fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1` - hence in your case `zipWithIndex` gives `(Int, Int)` type instead of expected `Int`, and function inside returns `Int` - so at the end infered type you see `Any` - common ancestor between `(Int, Int)`  and `Int`.

And `foldLeft[Z](zero: Z)` has infers `Int` because you give `0`

Comment: It would be good to explain the differences between `fold` and `foldLeft` and why that resulted in the `Any` type.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez almost done, thanks!