# Applying fold function on a List of HashMap and return a List of another type in Scala

Tags: list, scala, hashmap, fold

I am trying to use the fold function on Lists that contain elements of different types.
Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
val list: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 1)
val listOfMap: List[Map[String, Int]]= List(Map("a" -> 1), Map("a" -> 2))

def addN(list: List[Int], n: Int) = list.map(_+n)

val result = listOfMap.fold(list)((x, y) => addN(x, y("a")))
```

I am expecting the `result` will be a List of Integer:

`List(4, 4, 4, 4)`

However, the error that I got were Type Mismatch for:

**x** : Required: List[Int], Found: Iterable[Any] with Partial Function[Int with String, Int] with Equals

**"a"**: Required: Int with String, Found String

Comment: val result = listOfMap.foldLeft(list)((x, y) => addN(x, y("a"))) is what you want ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111440/scala-fold-vs-foldleft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fold don't do what you think.
For this kind of problem, Scala standard Library Documentation is your friend : https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/index.html

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1
```

Folds the elements of this collection using the specified associative binary operator.

You need foldLeft instead

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

Applies a binary operator to a start value and all elements of this sequence, going left to right.

Note: will not terminate for infinite-sized collections.

in your case

```
val result = listOfMap.foldLeft(list)((x, y) => addN(x, y("a")))
//List(4, 4, 4, 4): scala.collection.immutable.List[scala.Int]
```