# Scala: Why foldLeft can't work for an concat of two list?

Tags: list, scala, fold

Defining a concat function as below with foldRight can concat list correctly

```
def concat[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = (xs foldRight(ys))(_ :: _)
```

but doing so with foldLeft

```
def concat1[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = (xs foldLeft(ys))(_ :: _)
```

results in an compilation error `value :: is not a member of type parameter T`, need help in understanding this difference.

**EDIT :**

Just in case someone might be looking for a detailed explanation on folds
http://lampwww.epfl.ch/teaching/programmation_avancee/documents/programmation_avancee_5_en-2x2.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What 's the difference between foldRight and foldLeft in concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547305/what-s-the-difference-between-foldright-and-foldleft-in-concat)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Arguments order in `foldLeft` is not the same as in `foldRight`.

```
xs.foldRight(ys){(element, aggregator) => element :: aggregator}

xs.foldLeft(ys){(aggregator, element) => element :: aggregator}
```

With placeholder syntax for `foldLeft` - `(_ :: _)` - you are trying to do something like this: `aggregator :: element`. This [means](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2827293/406435) `element.::(aggregator)` and there is no `::` method in `element` (type of `element` is `T`).

Comment: How do they differ conceptually and what are the scenarios that I can them respectively

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar a look at the documentation would answer that. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253978/difference-between-fold-and-foldleft-or-foldright and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446419/how-do-you-know-when-to-use-fold-left-and-when-to-use-fold-right

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar `foldLeft` is more natural for List. `foldRight` requires reversing of the list first and it is slower.

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar: in addition to Paul's comment: note that `foldRight` on `List` is [implemented](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L397) as `reverse` + `foldLeft` since `reverse` is the best way to traverse `List` from lats to first element.