# Collapse subsequence of matching elements in a Scala sequence

Tags: scala, collections

Given a Scala sequence...

```
val sequence: Seq = List( 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5 )
```

...say that I want to find all subsequences matching certain criteria, e.g. strings of odd numbers, and replace those with the result of some operation on that subsequence, say its length, producing a new sequence:

```
val sequence2: Seq = List( 2, 4, 3, 2, 6, 1 )
```

(Yes, this is a fairly contrived example, but it's concise.)

So far the best I've been able to do is this ugly imperative hack:

```
val sequence: Seq[Int] = List( 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5 )

var sequence2 = List[Int]()   // this is going to be our result
var subsequence = List[Int]()

for (s <- sequence) {
  if (s % 2 == 0) {
    if (!subsequence.isEmpty) {
      sequence2 = sequence2 :+ subsequence.length
      subsequence = List[Int]()
    }
    sequence2 = sequence2 :+ s
  } else {
    subsequence = subsequence :+ s
  }
}

if (!subsequence.isEmpty) {
  sequence2 = sequence2 :+ subsequence.length
}
```

Is there an elegant (/ functional) way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [multiSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21803339/3189923) for spanning a list into sublists by given criteria, consider this solution for the problem depicted above,

```
sequence.multiSpan( _ % 2 == 0 ).flatMap {
   case h :: xs if h % 2 != 0 => List( (h::xs).length)
   case h :: Nil => List(h) 
   case h :: xs => List(h, xs.length) }
```

Note that

```
sequence.multiSpan( _ % 2 == 0 )
List(List(3, 1), List(4, 1, 5, 9), List(2), List(6, 5))
```

and hence we `flatMap` these nested lists by considering three cases: whether the condition does not hold and so we apply a function; whether it is a singleton list (the condition holds); or else whether the first element holds and the rest needs be applied a function.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a `fold`:

```
sequence.foldLeft(List(0)) { (soFar, next) =>
    if(next % 2 == 0) soFar :+ next :+ 0 else soFar.init :+ (soFar.last + 1) 
}.filter(_ != 0)
```

Or in a different style:

```
(List(0) /: sequence) { 
    case(soFar, next) if next % 2 == 0 => soFar :+ next :+ 0
    case(soFar, _) => soFar.init :+ (soFar.last + 1)
}.filter(_ != 0)
```

Or with a `foldRight` instead, which is sometimes more performant:

```
(sequence :\ List(0)) { 
    case(next, soFar) if next % 2 == 0 => 0 :: next :: soFar
    case(_, hd::tl) => (hd + 1)::tl
}.filter(_ != 0).reverse
```

You can read more about `fold`, `foldLeft`, `foldRight`, and other useful functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408880/reduce-fold-or-scan-left-right) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253978/difference-between-fold-and-foldleft-or-foldright).

I originally thought you were asking for all subsequences of a sequence.  That might be useful in similar situations, so I'll leave this here.  You can use `inits` and `tails` together to get all subsequences, and then use `filter` and `map` for your purposes:

```
val sequence = List( 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5 )
val subsequences = sequence.tails.flatMap(_.inits).toList.distinct
subsequences.filter(_.forall(_ % 2 == 1)).map(_.length)
```

Comment: That gets me `List(2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1)`. I think "all subsequences" is more combinatorial than what I need.

Comment: I totally misunderstood your question.  I get it now.  Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at a recursive implementation

```
def subSequenceApply(list: List[Int], predicate: (Int)=> Boolean, func: (List[Int]) => Int):List[Int] = list match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case h :: t if !predicate(h) => h :: subSequenceApply(t, predicate, func)
  case _ =>
    val (matchSeq,nonMatch) = list.span(predicate)
    func(matchSeq) :: subSequenceApply(nonMatch, predicate, func)
}
```

So given sequence in your example. You could run it as

```
subSequenceApply(sequence, _ % 2 != 0, _.length)
```